# Eclipse plugin performance degrades over time

Tags: java, performance, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have 2 `views` A and B, each has a `treeViewer`. 
B has a `listener` to tree `selectionChanged` in `view` A.
so each time I select  a `tree` item in A , the `selectionChanged` action is:

1- `setInput` to `tree` B

2- apply filter

3- expand all elements

The problem here is each time I click on a tree item in `View` A, the time it takes for `View` B to show up the tree items is increasing every time for the same selection in tree A.and items show up slower each time.

which part of the `selectionChanged` action could result in this performance problem !?

After some investigations, I found out that the method `TreeViewer.expandAll()` is the one causes that big delay each time. 
Is this an `Eclipse` issue or should I modify it ?

Comment: If you showed us the code for Steps 1-3 that you listed, we might be able to spot a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Performance bugs are hard to catch.  Try watching CPU, Disk activity and memory usage for your system as you perform those actions.  Check your code to see if there are any collections being built up that are not correctly initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Also, try installing some profiler, I would suggest [YourKit Profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/) it has 1 month trial version, which is I think would be enough to spot your problem. It has a lot of great features, like integration with eclipse and going into a problem place right from the profiler. Helped me a lot, when I was struggling with performance.

Comment: This was the first thing to try but it didn't help